# How to modify Button for Multitouch support on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, button, multi-touch

I want to have a button that responds to the Touch.FrameReported Up & Down events instead of the usual MouseDown and MouseUp events that would be used so this button can be used at the same time on Windows Phone as another button.
I already have a custom Button control with a MouseDown and MouseUp state, but am unsure how to make the Up and Down events there trigger the correct look - probably something with the VisualStateManager needs set but cannot figure out how to use it - solution needs to use the standard Button control as I'm merely extending it for the two states - as a button control with a normal and "pressed" state.
This is for a game screen within a larger Silverlight project, the rest of the project is standard Silverlight with the standard buttons and their normal behaviour, however in one place this needs to be Multitouch so this cannot be an XNA project instead as this would require porting 99% of the app to XNA where other features used are not supported - I've been able to extend custom controls to support multitouch but want the button to react this way too - plus I'm sure this will be of use to others, especially as this will most likely apply to Windows 7/8 development too.

---

Edit: Here is the Code and Generic.xaml for my button with the normal behaviour (OnMouseUp/OnMouseDown)

Code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace UXLibrary
{
    [TemplatePart(Name = "Pressed", Type = typeof(BitmapSource))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "Normal", Type = typeof(BitmapSource))]
    public class UXButton : Button
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty  PressedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Pressed", typeof(BitmapSource),
        typeof(UXButton), null);

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Normal", typeof(BitmapSource),
        typeof(UXButton), null);

        public BitmapSource Pressed
        {
            get { return (BitmapSource)GetValue(PressedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PressedProperty, value); }
        }

        public BitmapSource Normal
        {
            get { return (BitmapSource)GetValue(NormalProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NormalProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>Constructor</summary>
        public UXButton()
        {
            DefaultStyleKey = typeof(UXButton);
        }

        /// <summary>OnApplyTemplate</summary>
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();     
        }

    }
}
```

Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="local:UXButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:UXButton">
                    <Grid>
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="0.5"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Image x:Name="PressedImage" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{TemplateBinding Pressed}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="NormalImage" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{TemplateBinding Normal}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

---

Solution

```
<Style TargetType="local:UXButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:UXButton">
                    <Grid>
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MultiTouchStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SpecialTouch">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Image x:Name="PressedImage" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{TemplateBinding Pressed}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="NormalImage" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{TemplateBinding Normal}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Code:

```
/// <summary>Button</summary>
[TemplatePart(Name = "Wrapper", Type = typeof(Grid))]
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "SpecialTouch", GroupName = "MultiTouchStates")]
public class UXButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Pressed", typeof(BitmapSource),
    typeof(UXButton), null);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Normal", typeof(BitmapSource),
    typeof(UXButton), null);

    public BitmapSource Pressed
    {
        get { return (BitmapSource)GetValue(PressedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PressedProperty, value); }
    }

    public BitmapSource Normal
    {
        get { return (BitmapSource)GetValue(NormalProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NormalProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>Constructor</summary>
    public UXButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(UXButton);

    }

    /// <summary>OnApplyTemplate</summary>
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        Touch.FrameReported += (object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e) =>
        {
            Image pressed = (Image)GetTemplateChild("PressedImage");
            Image normal = (Image)GetTemplateChild("NormalImage");
            TouchPointCollection points = e.GetTouchPoints(null);
            foreach (TouchPoint point in points)
            {
                if (point.Action == TouchAction.Down && (point.TouchDevice.DirectlyOver == normal || point.TouchDevice.DirectlyOver == pressed))
                {
                    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "SpecialTouch", false);
                }
                else if (point.Action == TouchAction.Up)
                {
                    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", false);
                }
            } 
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: And this game is NOT made in XNA?

Comment: Why is this always asked, should add that it isn't in XNA to my questions in future! But not really that is a good point it supports multitouch better than Silverlight - but this is adding some functionality to a Silverlight project that makes use of the standard controls - but in one particular place they need to support multitouch - no where else.

Comment: can you show what you've done so far?

Comment: I've added the code for my button now, thanks!

Comment: Have added the Solution to My question hopefull this will help someone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, i think you need to create one more visual state rather than two parts ("pressed" & "normal").

```
// UPDATE: you need to get the Grid in order to know the touch area
[TemplatePart(Name = "Wrapper", Type = typeof(Grid))]
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "SpecialTouch", GroupName = "MultiTouchStates")]
public class UXButton : Button
```

Then in your custom button's constructor, subscribe to the FrameReported event,

```
    public UXButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(UXButton);

        Touch.FrameReported += new TouchFrameEventHandler(Touch_FrameReported);
    }

    void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
    {
        // UPDATE: get the Grid
        var wrapper = GetTemplateChild("Wrapper") as Grid;

        TouchPointCollection points = e.GetTouchPoints(null);

        foreach (TouchPoint point in points)
        {
            // UPDATE: also do the touch area check here
            // specify what touch you want
            if (point.Action == TouchAction.Down && point.TouchDevice.DirectlyOver == wrapper)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "SpecialTouch", false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in the style, you do the hide and show images in this visual state you just created. If you want to be able to dynamically change the normal and pressed images, of course you can just add your TemplateParts back in.

UPDATE: Also you need to give your root element which is the Grid a name and a background color,
like this,

```
<Grid x:Name="Wrapper" Background="Transparent">

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MultiTouchStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="SpecialTouch">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedImage">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is similar to something I tried - adding another state for TouchAction.Up for MouseUp produces the desired effect but when multiple buttons are used they all change state together no matter what I try - e.GetTouchPoints(null); or e.GetTouchPoints(this); makes no difference - just need each button to react on it's own independent of the others - they react to their own touch events

Comment: you mean you touched one button and the other buttons all changed their states?

Comment: Yes - I can have one working on it's own fine, but add some more and the other buttons sometimes trigger the down state when one is tapped - I have for example three next to each other and tapping the middle one made the left and right buttons enter their down state - sometimes it will work but more tapping produces multiple reactions from the other buttons. I am testing this on a Windows Phone device as I don't have any other way of doing multitouch anyway!

Comment: Hmm... Could you accidentally click the edge of other buttons? Try to increase the margin and see if it still happens?

Comment: I've spaced them apart however I've noticed it seems to be the first tap when the test app loads causes them all to register a "SpecialTouch" event - and after when tapping a button the second tap triggers a down event on all buttons - ie. tap button one it behaves fine after second tap - others show "down" state, tap button two and if goes to up state when tapped but when tapped again button one returns to down state and stays there!

Comment: oh... sorry i forgot you also need to set point.TouchDevice.DirectlyOver, will update the answer shortly

Comment: Thanks - have modified it as the grid was behind the images so wasn't picking up the touch events changed it to use the normal/pressed image and added an up event check to make sure they revert to normal state - have marked this as answer though

Comment: Sorry forgot to award to points, thought it happened when I marked as answer!